# Problems unit testing setInterval function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I am having difficulties testing window.setInterval function in my Javascript file.  Below is the scenario... basically I have a setInterval function in a function which I want to test:

```
var dummy = false; // global variable not set anywhere else
var INTERVAL_TIME = 20; // global variable not set anywhere else
function myFunction() 
{
    var id = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (...)
        {
            window.clearInterval(id);
        }
        else
        {
            if(...)
            {
                dummy = true;
            }
        }
    }, INTERVAL_TIME);
}
```

And I have the following test code in JsTestDriver:

```
TestMyFunction.prototype.test_myFunction() {
    myFunction();
    assertTrue(dummy);
}
```

Everytime the test executes, it fails and says dummy is false, as if the entire setInterval function was never called.  I tried playing around with the interval with no success.  If I put in an alert in the else clause, it popped up in a fraction of a second and disappeared (and test still fails).

The code works.  I have a feeling that it is a timing issue, where the test finishes earlier than the setInterval function, hence complaining that dummy is not set to true.  Any suggestions/solutions to this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the JsUnitMockTimeout.js to simulate the setInterval function.  It worked like a gem :)

Comment: Can you share your working code how you are using it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not put a setTimeout in your test, to delay checking for the value of dummy until after 25ms.

Answer (score 0):

`assertTrue(dummy);` is executed before the timeInterval of 20ms. Since you are using interval, do you perdiodically poll for the dummy value? First time poll is going to give you `false` unless you have a super slow PC.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ["JsTestDriver cannot perform asynchronous testing"](http://code.google.com/p/fwtemplates/wiki/FwTemplateJavascriptWalkthrough).  The only JS Unit testing frame work I have used with async support is [Qunit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit).

Qunit has [asyncTest](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/asyncTest#nameexpectedtest) which will work with ajax or timeouts.

PS: there a brand new JS Testing framework [Evidence](http://ajaxian.com/archives/evidence-that-your-code-will-work).  I have not tried it.